# How to write if else logic in SCSS file to convert hexadecimal color to rgba?

Tags: css, sass, colors

I have a scenario where I need to check if the provided color code is in Hexa or Rgba format, and based on that I need to change the value. I tried the below code but dosen't seems to be working.
Can some one please help me on that. I am new to this.

```css
$newccolor: #57a6ba;
@if $newccolor.startsWith("#") {
  $newccolor.replace('#', '%23');
}

@else if $newccolor.startsWith("rgba") {
  // then convert it to hexa
}
```

Comment: why do you need to do it in SCSS? Looks like your problem should be solved in another way